# Laplace Transform of an integral - Convolution Theorem not feasible

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I need to evaluate the Laplace transform of the following integral:

$$
\phi(t)= \int_0^{t_0} K(t-x)f(x)dx
$$

Note that the constant upper limit of the integral is different from the time variable, so that straightforward application of the Convolution Theorem is not feasible. I have an explicit functional form of the **Laplace Transform of** the Kernel $K()$, but not of the function $f()$ or its transform.

Any tips, pointers, hints or even answers would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Change the order of integration (if that's justifiable, which it probably is).

Comment: I take it you mean something like $$
\phi(t)= \int_0^{t_0} f(t-x)K(x)dx
$$, but I still don't see how it would result in a tractable form, since the CT would still be inapplicable.

Comment: No, I mean $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}\int_0^{t_0} K(t-x)f(x)\,dx\,dt = \int_0^{t_0} f(x)\int_0^{\infty} K(t-x)e^{-st}\,dt\,dx\,.$$

Comment: Doh! Yes, my bad! I've posted an answer below. Please review it for correctness - I forgot to mention that key point that $f(x)$ is zero outside of $[0,t_0]$. I do have a follow up question that could be a bit trickier. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the excellent suggestion by Daniel Fischer above, I've attempted a solution below:

The Laplace Transform of

$$\phi(t)=\int_0^{t_0} K(t-x)f(x)dx$$

is

$$
L[\phi(t)]= \int_0^\infty e^{-st}\int_0^{t_0} K(t-x)f(x)dxdt
=\int_0^{t_0}\Biggl[ \int_0^\infty e^{-st}K(t-x)dt\Biggr]f(x)dx
$$

With the variable shift $y=t-x$, the inner integral can be written as

$$
\Lambda(s) = e^{-sx}\int_0^\infty e^{-sy}K(y)dy=e^{-sx}\bar K(s)
$$

where the bar indicates a Laplace Transform. Substitution into the outer integral yields

$$
L[\phi(t)]=\bar K(s) \int_0^{t_0}e^{-sx}f(x)dx
$$

Since $f(t)$ is zero outside of the interval $[0,t_0]$, the upper limit of the outer integral can be replaced by $t$, so that

$$
L[\phi(t)]=\bar K(s) \int_0^te^{-sx}f(x)dx=\bar K(s) \bar F(s)
$$

Comment: When you substitute $y = t - x$, the lower integral limit changes from $t = 0$ to $y = -x$. If $K$ vanishes on $(-\infty, 0)$ we can of course omit the $[-x,0)$ part of that integral, but then, in conjunction with $f$ vanishing outside $[0,t_0]$, $\phi$ is the ordinary convolution of $K$ and $f$, so you could directly apply the convolution theorem.

Comment: In the actual problem that I have, $f(t)$ is a piecewise continuous function over several sub-intervals, so that the actual integral that I want to break up is
$$\phi(t)=\int_0^{t} K(t-x)f(x)dx=\phi(t)=\int_0^{t_0} K(t-x)f_A(x)dx +\int_{t_0}^{t} K(t-x)f_B(x)dx $$ My problem is that the Kernel $K(t)$ cannot be expressed in the form $K(t) = P(t,t_0)K(t_0)$  which would allow me to carry over $$\int_0^{t_0} K(t_0-x)f_A(x)dx $$ as a legacy term updated from one sub-interval to the next.

Comment: A quick clarification. You wrote that I could directly apply the Convolution Theorem. Wouldn't that the same Laplace Transform as that for $$\phi(t)=\int_0^{t} K(t-x)f(x)dx$$ ? - Note the upper limit is $t$ instead of $t_0$.

Comment: The application of the second shifting property doesn't work here. The limits of the integral don't match the step function. It also gives the wrong answer (try it with $K(t) = \exp(s_0 t)$ and $f(t) = \sin(\omega_0 t)$).

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar If $K(u) = 0$ for $u < 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin [0,t_0]$, then $$\int_0^t K(t-x)f(x)\,dx = \int_0^{t_0} K(t-x)f(x)\,dx.$$ For $t < t_0$ we then have $K(t-x) = 0$ on $(t,t_0)$, and for $t > t_0$ we then have $f(x) = 0$ on $(t_0,t)$.

Comment: Yes, I see my mistake now. However this brings up another issue. Going back to the form$$\phi(t)=\int_0^{t} K(t-x)f(x)dx=\int_0^{t_0} K(t-x)f_A(x)dx +\int_{t_0}^{t} K(t-x)f_B(x)dx$$, I can apply the variable shift $\tau=x-t_0$ to the second term, so that the Convolution Theorem can be used again. However, the first and second terms are evaluated over different time intervals, so it's not clear to me how I would go about evaluating the inverse transform. I'll have to use a function sampling technique here, as the Kernel $K()$ is in terms of Modified Bessel functions of the 2nd Kind.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, thanks for spotting the error in my use of the Second Shifting Property! I've fixed my answer above which is now also in line with what Daniel Fischer had pointed out.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I've posed a followup question where $f(t)$ is no longer zero for $t>t_0$, but is piecewise continuous at $t=t_0$. I've followed the logic you proposed, but cannot resolve it purely in terms of Laplace Transforms. I'd appreciate it if you could take a crack at it! Thanks

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421711/laplace-transform-of-an-integral-with-a-piece-wise-continuous-function